# Change easyButton State Within Server Function in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Does anyone know of a way to change the state of an easyButton inside the server function of an R Shiny app?

```
leaflet() %>%
    setView(lng = -70.4803, lat = 40.94404, zoom = 6) %>%
    addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery') %>%
    addEasyButton(
    easyButton(id = 'edit-btn', states = list(
      easyButtonState( 
        stateName = 'add-toolbar',
        icon = icon('toggle-off'),
        title = 'Edit',
        onClick = JS("
          function(btn, map) {
            Shiny.onInputChange('edit_btn', 'TRUE');
            btn.state('remove-toolbar');
          }"
        )
      ),
      easyButtonState(
        stateName = 'remove-toolbar',
        icon = icon('toggle-on'),
        title = 'Editing',
        onClick = JS("
          function(btn, map) {
            Shiny.onInputChange('edit_btn', 'FALSE');
            btn.state('add-toolbar');
          }"
        )
      ))
    )
)
```

Then I tried to change the state of this easyButton within a server function that triggers when another action button is clicked:

```
runjs("edit-btn.state('add-toolbar');")
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the shinyjs `click()` function. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("toggle_button","My Button"),
  actionButton("disable_button","Toggle State"),
  leafletOutput("my_map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle_button,{
    shinyjs::click("edit-btn")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$disable_button,({
    shinyjs::toggleState("edit-btn")
  }))
  
  output$my_map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = -70.4803, lat = 40.94404, zoom = 6) %>%
      addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery') %>%
      addEasyButton(
        easyButton(id = 'edit-btn', 
                   states = list(
                     easyButtonState( 
                       stateName = 'add-toolbar',
                       icon = icon('toggle-off'),
                       title = 'Edit',
                       onClick = JS("
          function(btn, map) {
            Shiny.onInputChange('edit_btn', 'TRUE');
            btn.state('remove-toolbar');
          }"
                       )
                     ),
                     easyButtonState(
                       stateName = 'remove-toolbar',
                       icon = icon('toggle-on'),
                       title = 'Editing',
                       onClick = JS("
          function(btn, map) {
            Shiny.onInputChange('edit_btn', 'FALSE');
            btn.state('add-toolbar');
          }"
                       )
                     ))
        )
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Any idea how to disable the easyButton after rendering the leaflet  map (secs after page load)? I tried the `onRender` function in `htmlwidgets` using `%>% onRender("$('#crop-btn').disable();")`, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can use shinyjs::toggleState or shinyjs::disable. Edited the code above with an example.

Comment: Thanks @sada93, that helps! But I was hoping to disable the easyButton right after the leaflet map renders and before the user has time to interact with the UI. Any ideas?

Comment: Also tried this with no luck `%>% onRender("function(el, x, data){var m = this; const elem = document.getElementById('crop-btn'); m.whenReady(function(){elem.disable();});")`.